# ACL for web browsing only

Tags: networking, router, dns, firewall, acl

I have a TP-Link ER605 connected to my Comcast Business router. The firewall on the Comcast router is set up and working fine. Unfortunately, the TP-Link's ACL is either missing something or configured incorrectly. I have been working with firewalls and ACLs for my servers online with AWS, Linux, and Windows. Still learning, but this one has me stuck.

The goal of this firewall is to block everything except HTTP, HTTPS, and UDP DNS - both input and output.

[image]

**THE PROBLEM**
If I delete BLOCK_REMAINING, I can connect to the internet. I do not want to delete that, of course. This method has worked for me (blocking both input and output, with ports 1024-65535 and http protocols only) on other operating systems and in AWS.

**EXPLANATION**
THIS_ROUTER = the TP-Link router (192.168.0.1). WORKSTATIONS are the individual IPs of the allowed computers on the network. ALL_SUBNETS are both 192.168.0.0/24 and 10.1.10.0/24. The first two are for the WAN interface so it can communicate with the Comcast router (10.1.10.1). The next two are for the TP-Link router to communicate with the Workstations. The goal of the LOCAL_BLOCK_IN/OUT is to prevent other computers on the local network from communicating with each other. Then there are the HTTP, HTTPS, and DNS allow blocks. The service types are allowing ports 1024-65535 on the opposite side and 80,443,& UDP 53. BLOCK_REMAINING_IN/OUT does just that, blocks the remaining protocols, addresses, and ports.

Comment: What happens if you change the "Interface" to "WAN" for rules 7, 9, and 11?

Comment: Nothing. Still getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

Comment: What are your actual service definitions like? How does "DNS_UDP_IN" differ from "DNS_UDP_OUT"? (Also, why aren't there rules for DNS_TCP? And given the router most likely has a stateful firewall, not just a stateless ACL, do you actually *need* the _IN rules?)

Comment: The DNS_UDP_IN/OUT was put there just to keep the pattern & in case I change them... They're defined the same. Source range 53-53 & Dest. range 53-53. For DNS, I kept it simple. I've tried adding TCP DNS with the same results. & I assumed that I did in order to filter both incoming and outgoing packets.

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem (at least one of the problems) – the source port of DNS queries _isn't_ 53, and the destination port of DNS replies isn't 53 either.

Comment: OK. Sorry, I've been working with L2TP too much and it's still too early in the morning lol. It's odd - internet is working off and on (maybe dns cache). I had a successful connection to websites like google and Facebook even before fixing the source/dest ports for DNS. After changing the DNS to TCP/UDP and your recommendation, it's still not working.